# How to apply validations on submit or blur for reactive forms of angular 4?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular4-forms

I am working on angular 4 project. In which, I used reactive forms and angular validations. All the validation messages are shown on focus out of field. But I want to show validation messages on submit button also.
Html Code:

```
<form [formGroup] = "addNewCustomerForm" (ngSubmit) = "submitAddNewCustomerForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" [class.alert-border]="addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].touched" placeholder="Ex: James" formControlName="first_name">
    </div>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].touched" class="required alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid first name.</small>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('pattern') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].touched && !addNewCustomerForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('required')" class="patern alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid first name.</small>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" [class.alert-border]="addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].touched" placeholder="Ex: Lee" formControlName="last_name">
    </div>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].touched" class="required alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid last name.</small>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('pattern') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].touched && !addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('required')" class="patern alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid last name.</small>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" [class.alert-border]="addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].touched" placeholder="Ex: example@xyz.com" formControlName="email_id" (focusin)="emailExist = false" (focusout)="checkEmailExistance($event)">
    </div>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].hasError('required') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].touched" class="required alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid email.</small>
    <small *ngIf="addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].hasError('pattern') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].touched && !addNewCustomerForm.controls['email_id'].hasError('required')" class="patern alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid email.</small>
    <small *ngIf="emailExist" class="alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> This email already exists. Please try with different email.</small>
</form>
```

ts code:

```
 this.addNewCustomerForm = this.formGroup.group({
        first_name           : [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.regExpression)]],
        last_name            : [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.regExpression)]],
        email_id            : [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]] });

submitAddNewCustomerForm(){
  if(this.addNewCustomerForm.valid)
  {
    console.log(this.addNewCustomerForm.value);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options,

One :- have a Boolean variable in your submit function and set true in case if form is invalid and use that in your error block's ngIf condition.
Below is an example of the same.

```
  submitAddNewCustomerForm(){
    if(this.addNewCustomerForm.invalid)
    {
      this.showError = true;
    }
  }
```

And in html error

```
 <small *ngIf="(showError || (addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('pattern') && addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].touched)) && !addNewCustomerForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('required')" class="patern alert-error"><i class="material-icons">error</i> Please enter a valid last name.</small>
```

And Second option is you mark each control dirty by using

```
this.controlName.markAsDirty()
```

Or by

```
this.form.get('controlName').markAsDirty()
```

Comment: If we use your first approach, if only one field has validation error, all other fields also shown validation message, because we use showError || condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with the form directive as per shown **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14527#issuecomment-280726674)**

For the submitted part, add the template reference to your form along the rest you have:

```html
<form .... #formDir="ngForm">
```

Then you can just add `formDir.submitted` to your if statements, for the blur functionality you can just check that the field has been `touched`. So for your `if` statement, I would assign the actual form control to a variable, so that we can shorten the code, this is of course not necessary, but for readability I would do that and for example use a variable for `first_name` after building the form:

```html
this.firstNameCtrl = this.addNewCustomerForm.get('first_name');
```

Then in your template you can do the following to achieve what you want:

```html
<small *ngIf="firstNameCtrl.hasError('required') && 
              (formDir.submitted || firstNameCtrl.touched) ">...</small>
```

Comment: Its only works on submit, But I want to show validation messages on focus out of fields as well as submittion of form.

Comment: @TarnjeetSingh Check updated answer, missed that you wanted both functionalities. But now it should do what you want :)

Comment: @TarnjeetSingh, did the answer work? Or the other? :)